# Geometry type issue with st_intersection() between polylines and polygons

Tags: qgis, postgis, intersection, clip, spatial-statistics

I clip a polylines vector layer with a polygon vector layer, containing one single polygon. I need my polylines to be clipped at the polygon's boundaries.

```
CREATE TABLE test AS (SELECT a.gid, st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) FROM lines a, polygon b WHERE st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom));
```

I can't visualize the `test` table in QGIS because the type of `geom` column seems not to be recognized (see image below, which is DB Manager GUI). Thus I tried to specify it within pgAdmin:

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MultiLineString) USING geom::geometry(MultiLineString);
```

This issues the following error message:

> ERROR:  Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (MultiLineString)

[image]

--

**EDIT :**

I tried to keep the geometry column from the polylines layer together with the `st_intersection()` function.

```
CREATE TABLE test AS (SELECT a.gid, a.geom, st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) FROM lines a, polygon b WHERE st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom));
```

This allows to display the table within QGIS but as there are 2 geometry columns produced, the clipping is not displayed and QGIS considers that 2 tables were created.

[image]

I need to make a clean clipping of my polylines layer resulting in a new table with a geometry columns having `geometry(MultiLineString)` type and displaying well in DB Manager.

Answer (score 6):

The ST_Intersection can produce different geometry-types in one go (image two lines intersecting at one point, returning a point) and likely therefore you are receiving linestrings and multilinestrings at the same time.

Try wrapping your ST_Intersection() in ST_Multi() so that it always returns a multilinestring, even when it is just a linestring, and check your output for anything else then a line (points).

As a bonus: try to alias your functions so they produce nice column names. So:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(geomA, geomB) AS geom
```

Comment: Thanks @tilt, but `st_multi()` does not do the job for me... I will post an answer with a solution I found afterward.

Answer (score 4):

OK, just found the solution on my own:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS (SELECT a.gid, a.geom, st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) FROM lines a, polygon b WHERE st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom));
```

I had to keep the geometry column from the polylines layer together with `st_intersection()` function.

Comment: This is not a good solution for the query will generate two geometry columns: `geom` and `st_intersection`. When opened with QGIS, the column `geom` is used to display the lines so the intersection (clipping) is not performed... Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Other solution to this issue:

1. Create a new table with the `st_intersection()` function:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE test AS (SELECT a.gid, st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom FROM lines a, polygon b WHERE st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom));
   ```
2. At this stage, geometry column's type is `geometry` with no more precision on the type of geometry (point, linestring, polygon, etc.). It is not possible to set a more accurate type:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MultiLineString) USING geom::geometry(MultiLineString);

   -- Error message:

   -- ERROR:  Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (MultiLineString)
   ```
3. Then, let's check [geometry type](http://postgis.net/docs/GeometryType.html) of `test` table:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT GeometryType(the_geom) FROM test;

   -- Result:

   -- geom
   -- geometry
   -- ----------------
   -- LINESTRING
   -- MULTILINESTRING
   ```

   There are 2 geometry types. This is why changing the type of geometry column is not accepted.
4. Update the geometry column for `LINESTRING` rows:

   ```
   UPDATE test SET geom = st_multi(geom) WHERE GeometryType(geom) = 'LINESTRING';
   ```
5. Now, defining geometry column type is possible:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MultiLineString) ;
   ```

Hope this can help!